# Umbraco 9 - How to get up and running with Examine

Tags: c#, umbraco, asp.net5

Is Examine up and running yet for Umbraco 9? If so does anyone have any example code so I can try and get up and running and test it?

I am looking for the equivalent of how we used to do it for Umbraco 8.

So something similar to the below. Adding a custom field into the search index etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Composer/Component way works really well for packages because you can register it without having to have the end-user change their Startup.cs file to call your methods. But in my own project, I'd just add calls to Startup.cs.

That said, I updated the [Our.Umbraco.GraphQL](https://github.com/umbraco-community/umbraco-graphql/tree/v9/dev/src/Our.Umbraco.GraphQL/Adapters/Examine/Types) package last week, and while it doesn't do custom indexes, it does query Examine. I didn't find I needed to change much of anything except perhaps some namespace references. I did have to update the maxResults parameter to instead pass in the ExamineOptions class with skip/take, as Stuart mentions at https://our.umbraco.com/forum/umbraco-9/106215-examine-skiptake, but otherwise, the same v8 code seemed to work fine in v9.